# Angular 2 lazy loaded modules with shared dependencies

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an angular 2 app with several lazy loaded modules built using the SystemJS builder.  3 of my 12 lazy modules share a dependency on a particularly large third-party library.

I can easily place the shared dependency in a dependencies bundle and load that via a script tag so that it's only downloaded once.  The downside is that pages that don't need it have to wait for it.

I can also easily place the shared dependencies into the lazy modules themselves so that pages that don't need it don't have to wait for it, but now modules that need it have to download it as part of their bundle even though it may have been downloaded by another module that has already been loaded.

Is there anything in angular 2 or systemjs that would allow a lazy module to be registered using 2 bundles?  I'd love to be able to create a dependencies bundle that is shared by those 3 modules, such that it's downloaded once by the first module that needs it, and then not downloaded again for the others.